# bookmarklet to change firefox images to low res?

Tags: firefox, images, bookmarklet

I'd like to know if there is a bookmarklet that changes the image resolution to low in forefox?

I often log onto my computer remotley and browse some websites with a fairly slow connection when I am out and about, so wondered if there was a quick way to change the quality of images on a website on the fly?

I've googled around and found nothing but posts on improving image quality!

Answer (score 1):

Can you do that at all? You can't affect how the images are stored on the server so you'll have to download them entirely anyway before you can display them - no matter the quality. You can view them in low-res, but that won't save you bandwidth.

The only way you could save bandwidth by reducing image quality is if you had a compressing proxy somewhere. You would connect to the web through this proxy. The proxy would have high bandwidth available, it would download all the pictures and recompress them on-the-fly. There are existing solutions like this, just try to google a bit.

Comment: when browsing from a remote computer, it is the images that slow down the connection - if the images that are being sent over the remote connection are lower res (even though the full res is downloaded on the local machine) it will save some bandwidth

Comment: Ahh, so that's what you mean. Are you sure it will work this way? The Remote Desktop connection doesn't care much about quality or resolution of the picture in FireFox. It just sees that the pixels from 100,100 to 500,500 are changed on the screen so it sends them all. Probably compressing them a bit, but maybe not. Have you tried lowering the color depth of your Remote Desktop connection (say, to 16-bits)?

Comment: …Are you talking about like over VNC or RDC? Are you sure compressing the images (by making them low res) would help? Wouldn't the protocol just send a high res version of a low res 'image'

Answer (score 1):

This is from another answer I posted on SU:

> Go through the Google servers. Google
>   has an option to format any page for
>   mobile devices. Just use
>   http://www.google.com/gwt/n?u=http://WhateverYouWant.com.

All links starting from the first site you use are converted to that format, so you can click any link without having to worry about writing all that again. It doesn't look pretty, but it's better than nothing. All images are **downscaled** and **lower quality**. Just remember, not all pages will look that great (superuser.com , for instance, looks awful), flash will not work (it is bandwidth consuming, so I don't really think you need it), but you will consume far less bandwidth.

Comment: This is pretty useful, thanks for that - do you know if there is a way to get a bookmarklet to add http://www.google.com/gwt/n?u= to the start of the webpage you are viewing?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I use this in Chrome; I've added it as a search engine. All I do is write "fast www.example.com" (fast is the keyword I use for the search engine).